# Is this PSU safe for this Christmas light string

Tags: amperage, watts, volts

I have an orphan 50 LED Static light string with label stating:-

"Complete supply chain 3V, 1.5W, IP44" which has no power supply.

I also have a power supply which is also orphaned i.e. it has no associated light string, but is of the same connection type as the light string above that has no power supply!
The label on the PSU states:-

220/240v - 50-60Hz 0.12A.

SEC: Urated = 5V

SEC: Uout = 6V

Prated = 3.6W

SELV IP44

The power supply does light the LED string, probably brighter than originally designed.
I have had it running for about 20 minutes with no apparent complaint, nothing getting hot!
Whilst I accept that the LED's may have a shorter life span at the increased illumination, is this a safe marriage of "orphaned bits"?

Thanks, and excuse my ignorance!

Comment: It depends what you mean by safety. For light string it is not safe. Fireproof is not safe. Electrical hazard depends on situation. Briefly, follow manufacturer's recomendation.

Answer (score 3):

Manufacturers (ab)use convenient connectors all the time, especially for nonstandardized cases like low voltage holiday lighting strings. The fact that part A plugs into part B is not a guarantee that they were designed to work together. The rated voltages do not match, and the fact that just eyeballing it you think it looks brighter than normal is a red flag. I don't think it's worth it when a new string of lights can be had for less than $10 and certainly not when your family's safety is on the line.

Comment: Thanks @vir, I was not too concerned about the over voltage, thinking that would just shorten the life span of the string without endangering life or limb! The mismatched Wattage was what made me uncertain if it was safe.